# Refactor jquery ajax call using the promise object

Tags: jquery

I am doing an async cross domain call with authentication.

When I have authenticated I retrieve the real application data with a generic get method:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    return {
        get: function (url, data) {

            // Call to authenticate before retrieve data
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'root/authentication',
                data: { user: root: password: root },
                dataType: 'json',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                complete: function (response) {

                    // Call to retrieve application data
                    $.ajax({
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.withCredentials = true;
                        },
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: root + url,
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: true
                        },
                        async: true,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        crossDomain: true
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

the **above** data call is called by another non-generic code:

```
define(['cors'],
    function(cors) {
        return function CustomerService() {            
            function getCustomers() {
                return cors.get('/customers');
            }
            return {
                getCustomers: getCustomers
            };
        };
    })
```

In my knockoutjs viewmodel I want to do this:

When the asyc call is made execute the renderCustomers function and update the UI.

```
 $.when(customerService.getCustomers())
            .done(renderCustomers)
            .fail();


        function renderCustomers(customers) {

            // Add data to knockout observables
        }
```

What do I have to change that I get my customers into the renderCustomers function?

Right now customers is undefined and I guess thats because my ajax call is not correctly setup for the promise.

Comment: Your `get` function should return the `$.ajax` as in `return $.ajax({...})`.

Comment: That won't work because he has nested ajax calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first snippet, your Ajax call does not do anything with the customer data on success.  Try this:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    return {
        get: function (url, data) {
                var result = $.Deferred();  // create a deferred object to return
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'root/authentication',   // you had a typo here
                data: { user: root: password: root },
                dataType: 'json',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                complete: function (response) {
                    // Call to retrieve application data
                    $.ajax({
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.withCredentials = true;
                        },
                        type: "GET",
                        url: root + url,
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: true
                        },
                        async: true,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        crossDomain: true
                    }).done(function(responseData){
                            // resolve the manually created deferred object, and send it the customer data
                        result.resolve(responseData);
                    });
                }
            });
            return result; // return your deferred object
        }
    };
});
```

Note that calling '*done*' on ajax is the same as calling '*success*.'  By returning the Deferred, you'll be able to use cors.getCustomers() as a deferred itself.

You can refactor your final snippet to remove the '*when*' call and use the deferred from *getCustomers* directly and bind your knockout there:

```
customerService
    .getCustomers()  // this returns an deferred now so you can add done and fail events
  .done(function(customers) {

        // Add data to knockout observables
        var elem = document.getElementById('myelement');
        ko.applyBindings(customers,elem);
    });
```

Comment: For the 2nd ajax request I get this error: "Cannot call method 'done' of undefined"

Comment: That's strange.  Try using success instead and see what happens.  What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: v1.9.1 and .success on the getCustomers().success(...) and in the cors did not work either. success is undefined.

Comment: getCustomers().success(...) won't work because success is only for ajax objects.  All ajax are deferred, but not deferred are ajax.  However, this problem is secondary to the first one, we need to fix that first.

Comment: OK the first one is fixed. I do not know why (played too much...) but now I register the .done() in my cors and in the viewmodel I do: customerService.geCustomers().done(renderCustomers);

Comment: The NEW problem is this: the renderCustomers is not fired when I am finished with debugging the ajax.done(  result.resolve(responseData); ). Why this?

Comment: The OLD problem seemed to be this: When I do not use $.when(...).done(...) then the done is undefined. When I use the $.when(...) then done is called in the ajax data call but the callback is not fired :/

Comment: WORKS! sorry man I had a typo... and a big Thank you. I also upvoted your answer with +1 ;-)

Comment: You have something broken on your side of the code that I can't see.  I duplicated this answer on jsfiddle (with modifications so it would work with jsfiddle) and it worked fine. http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingsites/DqD9W/5/